# Execute program in shell script using php

Tags: php, bash, macos, shell, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to automatise some Unity3D process to can call this from a PHP script.

I've already create an shell script that call some UNITY command line to create a project and for execute methods and if I use it in the terminal, works fine. 
The problem is when I use it into a PHP script:
 - I'm using `shell_exec` command to execute my script and all shell methods works (ls, mkdir, echo) but when I call to application nothing happend.

I was reading that is a permission problem into apache but after some hours I still without find a solution so.

I've mounted a server in my mac (Sierra) enabling apache and PHP 5 to test.

Regards, 
Gabriel

**EDIT 1** 
I add here my code

This is my `shell_script` that works fine if i execute it in a terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

UNITY_EXEC=/Applications/Unity_5.6.1f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity

if [ -z "$2" ]; then echo "You must provide a path to the bundle assets and a path to the resulting bundle."; exit 1; fi

export UNITY_ASSET_BUNDLE_PATH=${2}

CREATION_TIME=`date +%s` 
ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/AssetBundle-${CREATION_TIME}

echo "Creating temporary project."; 
${UNITY_EXEC} -batchmode -quit -createProject ${ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR};

echo "Copying resources from source folder to assets folder.";
cd $1; cp -r . ${ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR}/Assets;

echo "Finding assets."; 
cd ${ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR}; 
ASSETS_TO_BUNDLE=`find Assets -type f -not -name *.meta -not -name .DS_Store -not -name AssetsBundler.cs | sed 's/^.\///g' | sed 's/^/assetPathsList.Add("/g' | sed 's/$/");/g'`

mkdir ${ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR}/Assets/Editor/;
cat << EOT >> ${ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR}/Assets/Editor/AssetsBundler.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;

public class AssetsBundler{
    public static void Bundle(){
        List<string> assetPathsList = new List<string>();
        ${ASSETS_TO_BUNDLE}
        ArrayList assetList = new ArrayList();
        foreach(string assetPath in assetPathsList)
        {
            UnityEngine.Object[] assets = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(assetPath);
            foreach(UnityEngine.Object asset in assets)
            {
                assetList.Add(asset);
            }
        }
        UnityEngine.Object[] allAssets = (UnityEngine.Object[]) assetList.ToArray(typeof(UnityEngine.Object));

        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(allAssets[0], allAssets, "${UNITY_ASSET_BUNDLE_PATH}", BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets, BuildTarget.Android);
    }
}

EOT

echo "Building the bundle."; 
${UNITY_EXEC} -batchmode -quit -projectProject ${ASSET_BUNDLE_PROJECT_DIR} -executeMethod AssetsBundler.Bundle;
```

And this is my `PHP_script`

```
<?php

$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('./AssetBundleBuilder/');
$output = shell_exec('./AssetBundleBuilder ./Bundlify ./result.unity3d');
chdir($old_path);

echo $output;

?>
```

If i execute my PHP script from firefox, i receive as output all `echo` messages so thats tell me that the script is working. The thing is that the UNITY calls doesn't works.

Comment: Show some code friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll response my self.

Finally i got a solution using sockets. I've created a server socket in python to call the bash script in every connection and my client socket is in php that is the file that i call from a browser.

Thanks!
Gabriel